# Why would this javascript code not work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Supposedly this code is not supposed to work, yet I don't understand why not. Thanks for any help.

```
function myFunction() {
        var intface = document.createElement("div");
    var butn = document.createElement("div");
    butn.className = "btn";
    butn.innerHTML = "Click here";

    butn.onclick = function() {
        alert("pressed");
    }
    intface.appendChild(butn);
    intface.innerHTML +=" Press here";
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(intface);
    }
```

Comment: what are you expecting??

Comment: What exactly should (or should not) "work"? Please explain the issue properly. The JS seems to be syntactically valid if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `innerHTML += ...` you're rewriting the innerHTML and all the event handlers are lost.

It should be

```
interface.appendChild(btn);

var text = document.createTextNode(' Press here to see an alert');
interface.appendChild(text);

document.body.appendChild(interface);
```